# Can Googlebot crawl javascript generated content?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-applications, googlebot, google-crawlers

We have a web app that its content generated by javascript. Can google index those pages?

When we investigate this issue we always found solutions from old pages about using "**#!**" in links.

In our app the links are like this:
domain.com/paris
domain.com/london

When we use these kind of links, javascript populates content.

Is it wise to use **[HTML snapshot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-snapshots)** or do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

Yes they can crawl JavaScript generated content, as long as you are using pushstates.

---

### Detailed answer

It depends on your setup. Google and Bing CAN crawl javascript and AJAX based content **if your are using pushstates**. If you do they will handle content coming from AJAX calls, updates to page title or meta tags using javascript, and in general any such things.

Most frontend frameworks like Angular, Ember or Backbone already works with pushstates so in these cases you don't need to do anything. Check whatever system you are using to see how they do things. If you are not using pushstates you will need to implement it on your own or use the whole escapted_fragment html snapshot deal.

So if you use pushstate then yes, search engines can crawl your page just fine. If you don't then no, you will need to implement pushstates or do HTML snapshots.

**Bonus info** - Unfortunately Facebook does not handle pushstates, so the facebook crawler needs either non-dynamic og-tags or HTML snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

"Generated by JavaScript" is ambiguous. That could mean that you are running a JS script on the server or it could mean that you are making an AJAX call with a JS API. The difference appears to matter as far as Googlebot is concerned. But you don't have to take my word for it, as there is empirical proof of what Googlebot will and won't currently cache as far as JavaScript content in the form of live experiments using both the [XMLHTTPRequest API](http://www.doesgoogleexecutejavascript.com) and the [Fetch API](http://www.doesgoogleexecutejavascript.net). So, as you can see, server-side rendering is still going to be the best way to go for SEO.